# Using a code library for Android with Apache 2.0 license

Tags: android, apache-license

If:

1. I want to create an app (e.g. for a business who wants all its
   employees to download the app from Google Play freely)
2. I do not have an "about" button in the app.
3. The app is closed source.

How do I handle code libraries using Apache 2.0? I guess it is a "no-go"...

(But as I have yet to come up with a good way to make an about button when making solutions for customers - I want to make sure.)

Comment: All mobile apps (and all GUI frameworks, for that matter) have some kind of mechanism for doing an About page.  If you doubt this, download Angry Birds Free, run it, click on the Gear icon, then click on the `i` icon.  Angry birds runs on Android, iOS and Chrome (and possibly a few other platforms).

Comment: I would of course of not have a problem with it were it for my own products - but apps branded/coded for a customer is another kind of problem since customers may dislike it. But of course, you are correct in the sense that if a customer dislikes it - they gotta pay the price increase of buying commercial libraries.

Comment: Um, what I am saying is that you can fulfill the Apache license terms, using the tools you already have.